# how to update SharedPreference from other activity?

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I have created SharedPreference in my LogIn class and i put in in a method SavedPreference()

### LogIn.java

```
public void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();

}
```

now in my other activity, i want to update it or put string to it by calling the method and adding these paramaters after clicking the ok button.

### Menu.java

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String oldpassword = oldpass.getText().toString();
                    String newpassword = newpass.getText().toString();
                    if (LogIn.s.toString().equals("1234")) {
                        if (oldpassword.toString().equals("1234")) {
                            logIn.SavePreferences("password",newpassword);
                            Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"New password saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"Old Password is not correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (oldpassword.equals(LogIn.realpass)){
                            logIn.SavePreferences("password",newpassword);
                            Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"New password saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"Old Password is not correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

But after clicking ok, my app crashes and LogCat shows this

```
02-06 13:21:55.834 6327-6327/com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso, PID: 6327
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
                                                                                at com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso.LogIn.SavePreferences(LogIn.java:191)
                                                                                at com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso.Menu$3$1.onClick(Menu.java:133)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

LogIn.java:191 is this `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`

and Menu.java:133 is this `logIn.SavePreferences("password",newpassword);`

Answer (score 3):

Better to pass the `context` as a `argument` in **SavePreferences**

```
public void SavePreferences(String key, String value,Conext mContext){

 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
 .....
}
```

Comment: thank you! it did work! but it still didn't change my password, i think there is something wrong with my code, this is written in the LogIn.java file, i wrote another SharePreference because it would give an error if i use it outside the method
(https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/12650497_1207815212580451_1094779474_n.jpg?oh=78f47e58ecd4ffeb33c51c087b52a50e&oe=56B7EA6B&__gda__=1454898490_c9a1e9c50ffe4ceeaf949cdd39697dd8) 
sorry i don;t know how to add codes in comments

Answer (score 0):

make that method `static` because that way you will be able to update it from any other `activity` inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write the function `SavePreferences(String key, String value)` in the Application class instead of any activity as it can be then used in multiple activities then you can easily call that function with the instance of your application for example

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    //your app constructors and other related code
    ....
    ....

    public void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();

    }
    ....
    ....
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    //your Activity code
    ....
    ....

    private void MyFunction(){
        //assuming you have a static getter for the application object
        MyApplication.getApplication().SavePreferences("password",password);

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, unfortunately i still lack knowledge about android and doesn't know how to implement your code im my app.. 

im trying to achieve saving my password inside a sharedpreference, but in default the password is set to 1234 

so when the sharedpreference is empty, the password is 1234 and when it is updated (from another activity) it will compare if the oldpassword typed in the 1st edittext is equal to 1234(1st time updating) or if it is equal to the password inside the sharedpreference(2nd update onwards) then save the new password in the 2nd edittext, can you help me pls